# Can saved regression factor scores be used to test for normality in spss and used for further analysis?

Tags: regression, t-test, factor-analysis, normality-assumption, discriminant-analysis

I have already collected my data for my dissertation and as I have many variables I have done a factor analysis to drill down the variables to few factors. Then I have computed the mean of all the relevant variables of each individual factor. However, when I am doing a normality test on the factors, it is being negative, while normality test with the saved regression factor scores are yielding positive results. Which is correct?

Also, I wanted to know if I can used the saved regression factor scores to carry out further tests  like discriminant analysis, t-test and multiple regression analysis or should I stick to the mean of the factors?

I am quite confused on how to proceed. Any help would be much welcomed.
Thanks.

Comment: 1) Of course you may use factor scores for future analysis if it is reasonable for you to do. 2) Computing the mean (or sum) of highly loaded variables is just another way to arrive at 'factor scores'. (The _true_ factor scores can never be computed, so alternative methods to approximate them are warranted and ultimately of equal worth.)

Comment: Thank you so much @ttnphns for your reply. According to you, what would be the best option, using the factor scores or the mean of the variables?

Comment: If I'm not developing a psychometric instrument and so don't face the task to select "best" items I'd prefer factor scores as computed by factor analysis.

Comment: I've been thinking of going with the factor scores as well, you've just confirmed it. @ttnphns thank you so much, you've been a great help.